# T is an topology ( lower limit topology)

Tags: general-topology

I wanted to prove, that lower limit topology ($\tau_s =  \lbrace A \subset R : \forall_{x \in A } \exists_{y>x} [x,y) \subset A\rbrace \cup \lbrace \emptyset \rbrace $) is in fact topology, but I stopped at condition number (3) which is:

$
\lbrace U_t\rbrace_{t\in T} \subset \tau_s \Rightarrow \cup_{t \in T} U_t \subset \tau_s
$

Any union of elements of $\tau_s$ is an element of $\tau_s$

but what if I take two intervals [0,1) and [2,3), then the union of set of  this two elements does not seem like the element of $\tau_s$ because the union of set is not in the form of [x,y). I know I'm wrong, but why?

Comment: The system $\tau_s$ as written is indeed not a topology (you identified the reason). It is however a _basis_ of the lower limit topology.

Comment: As sets cannot be added together, the notion of  a sum of sets is an absurdity.  [0,1) and [2,3) cannot be  added.  Do you mean a union of sets?

Comment: @WilliamElliot There is the notion of a Minkowski sum of sets, i.e. $A+B = \{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$ where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of a vector space. But that is certainly different than the notion of set *union,* which is the operation in question here.

Comment: @DanielFischer hello Daniel, is this correct now ?

Comment: Now $\tau_s$ is the lower limit topology. But now it is easy to see that $[0,1) \cup [2,3)$ belongs to $\tau_s$, for $x \in [0,1)$ take $[x,1)$ and for $x \in [2,3)$ take $[x,3)$. And it's also to see that arbitrary unions of members of $\tau_s$ belong to $\tau_s$. If $x \in U_{t_0}$, then there is $y > x$ with $[x,y) \subset U_{t_0} \subset \bigcup U_t$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you, now I understand !

Comment: You do not mean $\lbrace U_t\rbrace_{t\in T} \subset \tau_s \Rightarrow \cup_{t \in T} U_t \subset \tau_s$, you mean $\lbrace U_t\rbrace_{t\in T} \subset \tau_s \Rightarrow \cup_{t \in T} U_t \in \tau_s$